# Copy groups from one user to another in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to run this PowerShell script that I found but it's not working for me and I'm getting an error could someone else check it and tell me if there is an issue here?

```
   $CopyFromUser = Get-ADUser userName -Server domainName -Properties MemberOf
$CopyToUser = Get-ADUser userName -Server domainName -Properties MemberOf
$CopyFromUser.MemberOf | Where{$CopyToUser.MemberOf -notcontains $_} | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $CopyToUser
pause
```

This is the error that I'm getting.

```
| A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
 | 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the group memberships one at a time, explicitly pass the target DN to the `-Identity` parameter:

```
$CopyFromUser = Get-ADUser userName -Server domainName -Properties MemberOf
$CopyToUser = Get-ADUser userName -Server domainName -Properties MemberOf
$CopyFromUser.MemberOf |Where-Object {$CopyToUser.MemberOf -notcontains $_} |ForEach-Object {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members $CopyToUser
}
```

Comment: And how would you write the full ps script?
(Sorry I don't have much background on PowerShell)

Comment: @ChenTamayev You're welcome. If you answer solves your problem, please consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark outline on the left :)